# parse a complex json string in C#

Tags: c#

```
{
  "irCurves": {
    "EUR": {
      "FCC-IRCUBE": [
        {
          "curveDefinitionId": "FCC",
          "curveFamilyId": "EUR/EURCURVE",
          "curveName": "EURCURVE",
          "marketDataSet": "FCC-IRCUBE",
          "referenced": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "GBP": {
      "FCC-IRCUBE": [
        {
          "curveDefinitionId": "FCC",
          "curveFamilyId": "value",
          "curveName": "value",
          "marketDataSet": "value",
          "referenced": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "USD": {
      "FCC-IRCUBE": [
        {
          "curveDefinitionId": "FCC",
          "curveFamilyId": "value",
          "curveName": "value",
          "marketDataSet": "value",
          "referenced": false
        },
        {
          "curveDefinitionId": "FCC",
          "curveFamilyId": "value",
          "curveName": "value",
          "marketDataSet": "value",
          "referenced": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

From the above json i need to pick only "USD", "EUR", "GBP".
How can i parse this json to get above values in C#.
Also This above json response will not be same always. Its a dynamic response, we cant track for the keys.

Comment: Have you considered using a JSON parser?

Comment: Please don't use unrelated question tags. This question has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Was it really harder to google "c# parse json"? There are thousands of examples

Comment: @KirkWoll i tried but, the keys keep varying. No luck.
Please give me some idea for parsing.

Comment: You should show what you've tried and tell the details of how you're having problems with your code. Else you're asking the same thing that's been asked over and over on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source lib for parsing and creating JSON files.

Sample below shows how to get the USD, EUR, GBP nodes using JSONPath

```
    public class IRCUBE
    {
        public string CurveDefinitionId { get; set; }
        public string CurveFamilyId { get; set; }
        public string CurveName { get; set; }
        public string MarketDataSet { get; set; }
        public string Referenced { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

            msg.AppendLine("CurveDefinitionId: " + CurveDefinitionId);
            msg.AppendLine("CurveFamilyId: " + CurveFamilyId);
            msg.AppendLine("CurveName: " + CurveName);
            msg.AppendLine("MarketDataSet: " + MarketDataSet);
            msg.AppendLine("Referenced: " + Referenced);

            return msg.ToString();
        }
    }

    using (var p = new ChoJSONReader("sample14.json")
        .WithField("USD", jsonPath: "$..USD.FCC-IRCUBE", fieldType: typeof(IRCUBE[]))
        .WithField("EUR", jsonPath: "$..EUR.FCC-IRCUBE", fieldType: typeof(IRCUBE[]))
        .WithField("GBP", jsonPath: "$..GBP.FCC-IRCUBE", fieldType: typeof(IRCUBE[]))
    )
    {
        foreach (dynamic rec in p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("USD:");
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (var curr in rec.USD)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(curr.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.